# How do I get Ant to recognize a file is in the project folder?

Tags: java, linux, ant

I am passing the file "testFile.txt" to my Java program as an argument using Eclipse and it works fine when I choose to run it normally. If I run the Ant build.xml in Eclipse with "testFile.txt" set as an argument, I get the error:

BUILD FAILED
Target "testFile.txt" does not exist in the project "MyProj1".

If I use Ant and pass the file in a linux shell using the line:

```
ant -Dargs="testFile.txt" run
```

it passes the String value "testFile.txt" but can not find the the corresponding file.  The file is in the MyProj1 folder which is where the src and build.xml are located.  Do I need to move the .txt file or modify the build file? If I have to modify the build file, what do I need?

```
<target name="run" depends="compile" description="run the project">
    <java dir="${build.dir}" classname="${main.class}" fork="yes">
        <arg line="${args}"/>
    </java>
</target>
```

Comment: What's the value of build.dir? the dir attribute of the java task should be set to the directory from which you want java to be started, i.e. MyProj1

Comment: Myproperties have the following values:                            <!-- global properties for this build file -->
  <property name="source.dir" location="src"/>
  <property name="build.dir" location="bin"/>
  <property name="doc.dir" location="doc"/>
  <property name="main.class" value="MyProj1.Project1"/>

Comment: So, you should probably use `<java dir="${basedir}" ...>` instead. Your text file is not in build.dir.

Comment: when I change `<java dir="${build.dir}" ...>` to `<java dir="${basedir}" ...>` i get a NoClassDefFoundError

Comment: java needs a classpath. And you should read the error message.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add

```
<arg file="testFile.txt"/>
```

To the java task, ie:

```
<target name="run" depends="compile" description="run the project">
    <java dir="${build.dir}" classname="${main.class}" fork="yes">
        <arg line="${args}"/>
        <arg file="testFile.txt"/>
    </java>
</target>
```

This will create an absolute path to the /path/to/build.xml/directory, which is where your file is.

If your file is in a subdirectory, prepend that to the arg file value, ../ also works the way you'd expect.

edit:

Directory structure

```
c:\project
|
+---PassFileViaAnt.class
+---build.xml
+---foo.txt
```

Class:

```
public class PassFileViaAnt {
    public static void main( String[] args ) {
        for( String arg : args ) {
            System.out.println( arg );
        }
    }
}
```

task:

```
<target name="run" description="run the project">
    <java dir="${build.dir}" classname="PassFileViaAnt" fork="yes">
        <arg file="${args}" />
    </java>
</target>
```

Command:

```
c:\project> ant run -Dargs="foo.txt"
```

Output:

```
[java] C:\project\foo.txt
```

Command:

```
c:> ant -f c:\project\build.xml run -Dargs="foo.txt"
```

output

```
[java] C:\project\foo.txt
```

Comment: "testFile.txt" is the name of the file I am passing to test my program, but someone else will be looking at my file and using a file they have named themselves which will not be the same name.  How do I make <arg file="testFile.txt"/> a generic statement to be the value of the arg passed?

Comment: Will they be using the build.xml to run the class? If yes, then have a property at the top for them to set, if no, you don't need to worry about it, just make sure the main() says what it expects when the args are wrong.

Comment: Also, the tester won't be modifying my build file and may not be saving their .txt file to my project folder.

Comment: yes, they will be using the build file.  They will be using a command line in a linux shell in the form ant -Dargs="someTextFile.txt" run

Comment: ...I haven't used it that way before, I'll need a couple minutes

Comment: arg file='${args}' will work provided there aren't args other than the filename

Comment: [java] java.io.FileNotFoundException: testFile.txt (No such file or directory)
     [java]     at java.io.FileInputStream.open(Native Method)
     [java]     at java.io.FileInputStream.<init>(FileInputStream.java:137)
     [java]     at java.util.Scanner.<init>(Scanner.java:653)
     [java]     at myProj1.Project1.main(Unknown Source)
I still get this response.

Comment: let me clean that up so it easier to read...  I still get the following response when I add the `arg file='${args}'` or `arg file='testFile.txt'`: `[java] java.io.FileNotFoundException: testFile.txt (No such file or directory)
     [java]     at java.io.FileInputStream.open(Native Method)
     [java]     at java.io.FileInputStream.<init>(FileInputStream.java:137)
     [java]     at java.util.Scanner.<init>(Scanner.java:653)
     [java]     at myProj1.Project1.main(Unknown Source)`